# Correctly write redirect in htaccess to force https and www version of a url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, redirect-loop

This is how I am attempting to force www and HTTPS urls in htaccess right now.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that this still creates a redirect loop. It first redirects to https://example.com and then redirects to https://www.example.com

Is there a way to correctly write this in htaccess so that it redirects to both https and www at the same time eliminating the redirect loop?

I have tried many examples that I have found here on stackoverflow and they all render redirect loops. Is this unavoidable?

Thanks!

Comment: _"It first redirects to `https://example.com`"_ - how? The _only_ redirect you have shown is to `https://www.example.com/$1`, so that code can not be responsible for that kind of redirect. Clear your browser history, resp. disable caching via dev tools - some browser cache redirects really fiercely, and that can easily mislead you in such situations. FYI, that's not really what one usually calls a redirect _loop_, that would be if you arrive at the original URL again at some point, and the whole process started from the beginning. You simply have one more redirect happen than you'd like ;-)

Comment: As for doing both in one go, a second condition, joined to the first one using the `[OR]` flag (default is AND, but you want to redirect when either of the two conditions is not met) should do the trick, `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` This should not have to be more complicated than that; the problems you referred to often arise when people needs this to be dynamic, taking the host name from a variable as well, and then getting https, non-www and the correct target host name right ...

Comment: @CBroe so if I have the code written above in my htaccess file and then I try to go to http://example.com this is the redirect loop given to me by redirect-cheker.org, 
http://algerstorage.com 301 Moved Permanently 
https://algerstorage.com/ 301 Moved Permanently 
https://www.algerstorage.com/ 200 OK 
Ultimately I just want to force www and https no matter how the url is typed in without creating the loop/chain. So I want to type in http://example.com and end up at https://www.example.com. Is this not achievable?

Comment: `http://algerstorage.com/` -> `https://algerstorage.com/` -> `http://www.algerstorage.com/` -> `https://www.algerstorage.com/`, that's the redirect chain according to my Chrome network panel. Again, I can not see how that could be happening with the redirect condition and rule as you have shown above. Are you sure that is not actually whatever script you (presumably) have running there as the index document, that doesn't do any URL checks and redirects maybe?

Comment: Can you give an example? What would cause that?

Comment: Well I don't know what you got running there? A WordPress maybe, some shop system, something self-written ...?